# generate a SHA256withDSA signature using Go and then verify it using Java

Tags: java, go, sha256, dsa

1. Go sha256 orign data then DSA sign it
2. print sign result by hex
3. use Java SHA256withDSA to verify first step result return false
4. i konw sha256 then DSA is difference SHA256withDSA
5. how can i do in Go to generate a sign, that can be verified using sha256withdsa in Java ?
6. do Go has any another third party library support ?

Go

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/dsa"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/asn1"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    pemData := []byte("-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
        "MIIBvAIBAAKBgQD9f1OBHXUSKVLfSpwu7OTn9hG3UjzvRADDHj+AtlEmaUVdQCJR\n" +
        "+1k9jVj6v8X1ujD2y5tVbNeBO4AdNG/yZmC3a5lQpaSfn+gEexAiwk+7qdf+t8Yb\n" +
        "+DtX58aophUPBPuD9tPFHsMCNVQTWhaRMvZ1864rYdcq7/IiAxmd0UgBxwIVAJdg\n" +
        "UI8VIwvMspK5gqLrhAvwWBz1AoGBAPfhoIXWmz3ey7yrXDa4V7l5lK+7+jrqgvlX\n" +
        "TAs9B4JnUVlXjrrUWU/mcQcQgYC0SRZxI+hMKBYTt88JMozIpuE8FnqLVHyNKOCj\n" +
        "rh4rs6Z1kW6jfwv6ITVi8ftiegEkO8yk8b6oUZCJqIPf4VrlnwaSi2ZegHtVJWQB\n" +
        "TDv+z0kqAoGBAIb9o0KPsjAdzjK571e1Mx7ZhEyJGrcxHiN2sW8IztEbqrKKiMxp\n" +
        "NlTwm234uBdtzVHE3uDWZpfHPMIRmwBjCYDFRowWWVRdhdFXZlpCyp1gMWqJ11dh\n" +
        "3FI3+O43DevRSyyuLRVCNQ1J3iVgwY5ndRpZU7n6y8DPH4/4EBT7KvnVAhR4Vwun\n" +
        "Fhu/+4AGaVeMEa814I3dqg==\n" +
        "-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----")

    p, _ := ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey(pemData)
    pp := p.(*dsa.PrivateKey)

    hashed := []byte{1}
    sha256 := sha256.New()
    sha256.Write(hashed)
    hashed = sha256.Sum(nil)
    r, s, _ := dsa.Sign(rand.Reader, pp, hashed)
    type dsaSignature struct {
        R, S *big.Int
    }
    var ss dsaSignature
    ss.S = s
    ss.R = r
    signatureBytes, _ := asn1.Marshal(ss)
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(signatureBytes))
}
```

Java

```
 @Test
    public void ttt() throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
        String pubKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
                "MIIBuDCCASwGByqGSM44BAEwggEfAoGBAP1/U4EddRIpUt9KnC7s5Of2EbdSPO9E\n" +
                "AMMeP4C2USZpRV1AIlH7WT2NWPq/xfW6MPbLm1Vs14E7gB00b/JmYLdrmVClpJ+f\n" +
                "6AR7ECLCT7up1/63xhv4O1fnxqimFQ8E+4P208UewwI1VBNaFpEy9nXzrith1yrv\n" +
                "8iIDGZ3RSAHHAhUAl2BQjxUjC8yykrmCouuEC/BYHPUCgYEA9+GghdabPd7LvKtc\n" +
                "NrhXuXmUr7v6OuqC+VdMCz0HgmdRWVeOutRZT+ZxBxCBgLRJFnEj6EwoFhO3zwky\n" +
                "jMim4TwWeotUfI0o4KOuHiuzpnWRbqN/C/ohNWLx+2J6ASQ7zKTxvqhRkImog9/h\n" +
                "WuWfBpKLZl6Ae1UlZAFMO/7PSSoDgYUAAoGBAIb9o0KPsjAdzjK571e1Mx7ZhEyJ\n" +
                "GrcxHiN2sW8IztEbqrKKiMxpNlTwm234uBdtzVHE3uDWZpfHPMIRmwBjCYDFRowW\n" +
                "WVRdhdFXZlpCyp1gMWqJ11dh3FI3+O43DevRSyyuLRVCNQ1J3iVgwY5ndRpZU7n6\n" +
                "y8DPH4/4EBT7KvnV\n" +
                "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
        String publicKeyPEM = pubKey
                .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "")
                .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "")
                .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
        byte[] publicEncoded = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyPEM);
        KeyFactory keyFactory1 = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
        X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicEncoded);
        DSAPublicKey pubKeyy = (DSAPublicKey) keyFactory1.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

        Signature sig1 = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withDSA");
        sig1.initVerify(pubKeyy);
        byte[] orignData = new byte[]{1};
        sig1.update(orignData);
        boolean flag = sig1.verify(HexUtil.decodeHex("first step result"));
        System.out.println(flag);
    }
```

Comment: Check whether both provide and require the same encoding. I've had a similar issue in the past where one language was providing the hash in base64 and the other requiring it in hex. There can also be a difference in the default padding character when using a block cipher.

Comment: java sha256 equale with golang sha256， but java sha256withdsa is not difference with golang sha256 then dsa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow  FIPS186-4 sections 4.6 and 4.7 golang should this

```
hashed := []byte{1}
pemData, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("config/secure/private.key")
p, err := ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey(pemData)
pp, ok := p.(*dsa.PrivateKey)
h := sha256.New()
h.Write(hashed)
hashed := h.Sum(nil)
if pp.Q.BitLen()/8 < len(hashed) {
    hashed = hashed[0 : pp.Q.BitLen()/8]
}
r, s, _ := dsa.Sign(rand.Reader, pp, hashed)
var ss dsaSignature
ss.S = s
ss.R = r
hashed, _ = asn1.Marshal(ss)
```

Answer (score 0):

i found in java

```
package sun.security.provider;

private BigInteger generateS(BigInteger var1, BigInteger var2, BigInteger var3, BigInteger var4) throws SignatureException {
        byte[] var5;
        try {
            var5 = this.md.digest();
        } catch (RuntimeException var9) {
            throw new SignatureException(var9.getMessage());
        }

        // this line split the hash256 redsult
        int var6 = var2.bitLength() / 8;
        if (var6 < var5.length) {
            var5 = Arrays.copyOfRange(var5, 0, var6);
        }

        BigInteger var7 = new BigInteger(1, var5);
        BigInteger var8 = var4.modInverse(var2);
        return var1.multiply(var3).add(var7).multiply(var8).mod(var2);
}
```

you can use in golang

```
    hashed := []byte{1}
    sha256 := sha2562.New()
    sha256.Write(hashed)
    hashed = sha256.Sum(nil)
    // you must split it 
    hashed = hashed[0:20]
```

the reason is sha256 result split in java , but glang not split

Comment: You mean truncate, not split; split would use both parts. Your code appears to be a disassembly; the [actual source for example here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/f9ea6cf9425f/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/DSA.java#l351) is clearer. Yes, truncating the hash if it is larger than the size of q is required by FIPS186-4 sections 4.6 and 4.7; the standard specifies bits while Java code uses 8-bit bytes, but this is okay because all approved q sizes are multiples of 8 bits and so are all approved hashes. If Go doesn't do this truncation, it is disobeying the standard.

Comment: Note if you want the _security_ level of SHA256 (128 bits) you should use DSA with 3072-bit p and 256-bit q, and then there will be no truncation because the hash size matches the q size; see section 4.2 in FIPS186-4. (Instead of referring to SP800-57, you can take my word the 4 standard p,q sizes (L,N values) have strength 80, 112, 112, 128.) But that's offtopic for SO.